# Как вывести знаки после запятой?

Tags: c++, double, точность

Я делаю вот так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    double index;
    double sumS = 0;
    cin >> index;
    for (double i = 1; i <= index; i++)
    {
        sumS += double(1 / i);
    }
    cout << setprecision(4) << sumS;
}
```

Но когда поступает число 1, то выводом будет 1, а не 1.000. Или при числе 2, выводом будет 1.5 вместо 1.500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам поможет

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(4) << sumS;
```

Только я бы на вашем месте не делал сугубо целочисленное значение значением типа `double`...

```
int index;
double sumS = 0;
cin >> index;
for (int i = 1; i <= index; i++)
{
    sumS += 1.0 / i;
}
cout << fixed << setprecision(4) << sumS;
```

Да, и, кстати говоря (хотя при обычных значениях это не играет роли), если есть возможность — лучше суммировать от малых слагаемых к большим:

```
int index;
double sumS = 0;
cin >> index;
for (int i = index+1; i-->0;)
{
    sumS += 1.0 / i;
}
cout << fixed << setprecision(4) << sumS;
```